# Jenkins, BitBucket and Proxy Errors 128 and 502

Tags: jenkins, proxy, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins configured to poll bitbucket periodically and download/build/deploy my app if there have been any changes (git push).  It works perfectly when I'm running Jenkins on my Windows PC behind a corporate VPN.

The problem I have is when trying to do the same on a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS) box residing inside the corporate network that has a proxy server configured.

Here's what my Jenkins Plugin Advanced tab looks like:
[image]

Here's what my Pipeline SCM looks like:
[image]

I've also tried disabling the proxy server by adding these lines to the top of the file at /etc/default/jenkins

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

I restarted Jenkins after making those changes and also removed the jenkins proxy config.

I've also mirrored my repo at gitlab and I get the same errors when Jenkins is configured with gitlab as I do with bitbucket.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd go about solving the problem:

- Try to complete the process without Jenkins. That is, writing a script of sorts that checks BitBucket and builds your app. If this fails, then the problem is with the machine, not Jenkins.

If the machine is at fault:

- Check its VPN configuration. Have the script working then try again with Jenkins.

Else (Jenkins is at fault):

- Consider using the BitBucket hook for Jenkins.
- If you're already using it (which you could let us know if so) or don't intend to use it, ensure that Jenkins is well-configured, as suggested by Carsten Hilber on [Jenkins' Atlassian site](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56453?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel):

> The settings were different between Jenkins and the bash. When
> building, jenkins loaded some proxy configuration that were set in a
> .gitconfig for the Jenkins user. When removing this, everything ran as
> expected.

Comment: It's a Jenkins issue.  I ended up disabling the proxy for the jenkins user